# validating jwt with RSA256 with Ktor

Tags: jwt, ktor

I'm using ktor for an api, and trying to implement jwt with asymmetric keys.

My code is as follows:

```
fun Application.configureSecurity() {

  authentication {
    jwt {
      val jwtAudience = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/testing"
      realm = "realm"
      val jwkProvider = JwkProviderBuilder("http://0.0.0.0:8080/")
        .cached(10, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .rateLimited(10, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build()
      verifier(jwkProvider, "http://0.0.0.0:8080/") {
        acceptLeeway(3)
      }
      validate { credential ->
        if (credential.payload.audience.contains(jwtAudience)) JWTPrincipal(credential.payload) else null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

service

```
fun generateJwt(user: User): String {

  val publicKey = readPublicKey("src/main/resources/keys/jwt_dev_public.key")
  val privateKey = readPrivateKey("src/main/resources/keys/jwt_dev_private.key", "cseWKyDM9nf6PPxbjfDA85BcY")

  return JWT.create()
    .withAudience("http://0.0.0.0:8080/hello")
    .withIssuer("http://0.0.0.0:8080/")
    .withClaim("name", user.name)
    .withExpiresAt(Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000))
    .sign(Algorithm.RSA256(publicKey, privateKey))
}
```

controller

```
fun Route.testJWT() {
  get("/generate_jwt") {
    val token = generateJwt(User(UUID.randomUUID(), "name", "password", "email"))
    call.respond(token)
  }

  authenticate {
    get("test_jwt") {
      call.respond("OK")
    }
  }
}
```

The Token is generated correctly, but when accessing a protected route, I get the following error

> 2023-04-12 14:29:01.634 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2] INFO  Application -
> 404 Not Found: GET - /.well-known/jwks.json in 3ms 2023-04-12
> 14:29:01.636 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.auth.jwt - Failed
> to get JWK com.auth0.jwk.SigningKeyNotFoundException: Failed to get
> key with kid null Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> com.auth0.jwk.NetworkException: Cannot obtain jwks from url
> http://0.0.0.0:8080/.well-known/jwks.json Caused by:
> com.auth0.jwk.NetworkException: Cannot obtain jwks from url
> http://0.0.0.0:8080/.well-known/jwks.json Caused by:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> http://0.0.0.0:8080/.well-known/jwks.json

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can understand it from the error response itself, when you defined `jwkProvider` here,     `val jwkProvider = JwkProviderBuilder("http://0.0.0.0:8080/")` , it is looking for JWKs at that endpoint, since you doesn't have anything here, it throws error. Read the error message properly. If you need to do RSA then you need to have your public keys somewhere for `JwkProviderBuilder ` to fetch from. I would recommend [this](https://www.scottbrady91.com/kotlin/json-web-token-verification-in-ktor-using-kotlin-and-java-jwt) article for you to read from.

Answer (score 1):

You need to publish the certificate file, which the `JwkProviderBuilder` is looking for. [Here](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/blob/1.6.8/codeSnippets/snippets/auth-jwt-rs256/src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt) is the example reference provided by [Ktor](https://ktor.io/docs/old/jwt.html).
If you want to host it at a different URL, or using an IAM Service(like Keycloak), you can create the provider like this:

```
val jwkProvider = JwkProviderBuilder(URL("http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs"))
            .cached(10, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .rateLimited(10, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build()
```